# Common Directory for 2 different PHP application in cPanel

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, directory, cpanel

so I have an application that has separate folder for admin and user since they have many different modules.

Admin

- admin.website.com (subdomain)

User

- website.com

Directory in cPanel

[image]

How can I access the 'resources' folder inside the admin application?
Thank you

Comment: Go one level up and do the stuff. i.e. `../resource/`

Comment: its already the public_html. cant go 1 more level up

Comment: Yes, but you have to go one level up in `admin` directory. For example, if you have to include a PHP file from `resource` in `index.php` file of admin directory, then just do `include ('../resource/file.php');` to access the file in resource dir.

Answer (score 1):

If your resources are PHP classes/files that you want to include - you can use

```
include('../resources/class.php');
```

If you are talking about static files (images/css/js) this is a bit problematic, because your root directory (from the browser's side) is `admin`.
What you can do is create a symlink (inside the `admin` directory) to the `resources` directory:

```
cd admin
ln -s ../resources/ resources
```

The above will create a new `resources` link inside the `admin` directory, and every request to a file (for example `admin/resources/FILE`) will actually be a request to `../resources/FILE`

Comment: what if I put the resources folder inside admin? so if i access it from user it will be /admin/resources. and from admin it will be /resources? is that okay?

Comment: Yes, that'd be okay too. Just choose the one that is easy to be implemented.